# How to assign values of one array to another array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got two arrays by name **actutalpricesarray** and **modfiedpricesarray** .

```
var actutalpricesarray =
[
    {
        "name": "apple",
        "price": 100
    },
    {
        "name": "orange",
        "price": 200
    }
]


var modfiedpricesarray = 
[
    {"name":"apple","price":20},
    {"name":"orange","price":30},
    {"name":"strawberry","price":40}
]
```

I want to assign  price values **modfiedpricesarray** to **actutalpricesarray** , so that the output of modfiedpricesarray will look like

```
[{"name":"apple","price":100},{"name":"orange","price":200},{"name":"strawberry","price":40}]
```

tried it this way

```
for(var i=0;i<modfiedpricesarray.length;i++)
{
    var fruitnamemodfiedprice = modfiedpricesarray[i].name;
    for(var j=0;j<actutalpricesarray.length;j++)
    {
        var fruitnameactualprice = actutalpricesarray[j];
        if(fruitnamemodfiedprice==fruitnameactualprice)
            modfiedpricesarray[i].price = actutalpricesarray[j].price;
        }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(modfiedpricesarray))
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/55230/

desired output of modfiedpricesarray should be

```
[
    {"name":"apple","price":100},  
    {"name":"orange","price":200},
    {"name":"strawberry","price":40}
]
```

Comment: So you want to keep the higher value of price ? That is why 100 and 20 becomes 100 in the final output ?

Comment: Your logic is alright. But you're comparing `fruitnamemodfiedprice` which is a string and `fruitnameactualprice` which is an object. Maybe you missed something there.

Comment: , thank you for pointing it out ,  corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is what you can do. I used the [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index of the desired fruit then I update the price. Check my [codepen](https://codepen.io/ulrichdohou/pen/EpYaey) too

```
var actutalpricesarray =[
  {
   "name": "apple",
    "price": 100
 },
  {
    "name": "orange",
    "price": 200
  }
]

var modfiedpricesarray = [
  {"name":"apple","price":20},
  {"name":"orange","price":30},
  {"name":"strawberry","price":40}
]

modfiedpricesarray.forEach((item,i) => {
  var fruitnamemodfiedprice = item.name;
  let index = actutalpricesarray.findIndex(x => x.name === fruitnamemodfiedprice);
  if(index !== -1){
    modfiedpricesarray[i].price = actutalpricesarray[index].price
  }
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(modfiedpricesarray))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly filter the array and then update value accordingly. You can test it below.

```js
var actutalpricesarray = [{
    "name": "apple",
    "price": 100
  },
  {
    "name": "orange",
    "price": 200
  }
];
var modfiedpricesarray = [{
    "name": "apple",
    "price": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "orange",
    "price": 30
  },
  {
    "name": "strawberry",
    "price": 40
  }
]

actutalpricesarray.forEach((data) => {
  modfiedpricesarray.filter((d) => d.name == data.name).forEach((d) => d.price = data.price);
});

console.log(modfiedpricesarray);
```